# DNF: show URLs for downloaded packages

Tags: dnf, url

Is there an easy way to get the URLs for the downloaded packages in DNF?

What I'm trying to achieve: I'm currently on a very expensive Internet plan, so I need to get links, download packages on a different connection and feed them to DNF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [canonical answer](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/issues/2030#issuecomment-1873673343) provided by a DNF developer:

> Use either `dnf repoquery <pkg> --location` or `dnf download <pkg> --url` (from dnf-plugins-core package) to list urls where a package could be downloaded from.

Answer (score 1):

Not foolproof (but what is?) but I tried this for `xemacs` using a local repository.

```
dnf list xemacs                           <- check the repository
   # and this returns xemacs.x86_64  21.5.34-35.20190323hgc0ed7ef9a5a1.el8 epel-RedHat
grep baseurl /etc/yum.repos.d/blah.repo   <- where blah defines the repository
   # this returns https://fseitl-build01p.ncifcrf.gov/oel/OL8/epel4oel/$basearch/
wget https://fseitl-build01p.ncifcrf.gov/oel/OL8/epel4oel/x86_64/xemacs-21.5.34-35.20190323hgc0ed7ef9a5a1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

You may have to repeat the process to pull in dependencies.

Comment: That's what I've already been doing but dang it's so not nice to do. I will file a feature request against DNF.